# What's the right way to reuse this one-liner?

Tags: bashrc, for

I recently came up with the following one-liner:

```
for f in *.mp3; do sha1sum $f | sed -r 's/[a-z]//g' | cut -c1-2 | awk '{ print ($1 >= 255) ? $1 - $1 + (1/3)*$1 : $1 }' | xargs -i id3v2 -T {} $f; done
```

I needed it because I've got an MP3 player that does not have a shuffle function. It was the only way I could find (in about an hour of trying) to give a suitably random distribution to track names. (At first I used `jot`, but this program does not update its random seed often enough to produce anything like random results. By the way, if anyone can think of a good way of doing this that actually works, I'm interested to hear about it.)

I tried storing it as an alias and got:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { print ( >= 255) ?  -  + (1/3)* :  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                  ^ syntax error
```

It just seems like there should be a suitably easy way of storing it in my `.bashrc`.

I'm aware that I could write it to a file and `chmod +x` it inside my `$path` with a shebang, but I prefer to use my `.bashrc` for things wherever possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really don't want to have this in its own file, you should use a bash **function**, not an **alias**.

How did you define your alias? If you wrote something like `alias bla="for f in *.mp3....` your `*` might be empty, if you did not escape it, because it is interpreted at evaluation-time of your bash, not at the time it runs. The same will be the case for `$f` etc.

Some other points: Why do you compare two digits (`cut -c1-2`) to 255? The number will always be smaller than 100.  Why do you write `$1 - $1 + (1/3)*$1`? This is simply ($1)/3.

Comment: you're right, and i'm stupid. i tried to define a function originally but i guess i made a typo since it wouldn't work. also, yeah, the math is a bit silly. i thought the max track number was 255 but that's just lame's default max track number. also, i've since moved on to using `octave <<< "trace(rand(19,19))" | grep "ans" | sed -e 's/\.//g' | awk '{print $3}' | cut -c3-5`